# Not receiving Botframework installationUpdate when app is added via GraphAPI

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

We are using GraphAPI to find an app in a Tenant's App catalogue and with admin's consent, we install the app (via Graph API) into a Team selected by the admin.

Once the app is installed, we expect Botframework to send an `installationUpdate` activity to the endpoint that we configured on the Azure Bot.

All of this working fine until we submitted the app for verification via Partner centre to publish the app to the Teams app store. Ever since then, we are not able to receive the `installationUpdate` notification when we install the app via GraphAPI.

However, if the app is installed directly from Microsoft Teams' Team manually, we receive the notification.

Has anyone faced similar issues and resolved them or can offer some help?

### Flow:

1. We have a Microsoft Teams app that we build with ID in the manifest: `15562290-1f82-4829-9638-452633a217d8`.
2. We side-load the app and make Teams admins approve the app.
3. They then come to our website and initiate the process of selecting the Team and installing the App into that Team via Graph API.

   1. We use `GET /appCatalogs/teamsApps` to find our app using `id` or `externalId`.
   2. We use `POST /teams/#{team_id}/installedApps` to install the app.
4. Once the app is installed, we expect the Botframework Activity to make a `POST` call with activity type `installationUpdate` so that we can fetch the `service_url`.

#### What is not working?

Botframework is not making the `POST` call to send the `installationUpdate` when the app is installed via GraphAPI using `POST /teams/#{team_id}/installedApps`.

#### What cases does it work?

Botframwork makes the `POST` call with `installationUpdate` when the app is installed manually from Microsoft Teams app by the user.

#### Other information

1. This was working fine until we submitted the app for verification via Partner centre.
2. After submitting the app via partner centre, the app is show in admin.teams.microsoft.com > manage apps.

   1. This is shown along side the side-loaded app.
   2. If we remove the side-loaded app from our Catalogue and install the App Store version of the App via GraphAPI, we get the API error code: 'Forbidden' and message: 'Trying to CreateTeamAppEntitlement for an App that is explicitly blocked by the tenant admin.'
3. Graph API client Azure app ID: `54a3aa2f-d1de-4565-800e-82f950e26306`.

Answer (score 0):

Let us discuss the solution for this problem in two different manners.

**1. Including REST API for GET and POST methods: **

The API references and continuous updates after the installation can be done perfectly when the bot was operated using REST API, instead of using Graph API. For the reference, I am attaching the URL for the procedure, that can be handy in development and re-checking the operations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

**2. Combining Graph API and REST API - Is that possible? **

No, is the point sure answer. There are several glitches phased by the researchers when they are using Graph API and the same, they reported by raising the ticket. For that reference, I am attaching the relevant thread.

So many researchers faced the same issue ***(This was working fine until we submitted the app for verification via Partner center.)*** and couldn't able to find the proper solution for this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/493106/graph-api-is-not-listing-all-installed-apps-in-a-t.html

Comment: 1. We do not use GraphAPI to operate the Bot. The messages sent to the bot are send via REST API. However, we use the GraphAPI to install the app. I suppose these are not the same. Are they?
2. We are not facing this issue at all.

Comment: Kindly check whether there are any operations done while creating the app which are blacklisted by Microsoft. Check https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/5713 as these issues are happening recently.

Comment: The link doesn't have any information about operations that are blacklisted by Microsoft. The issue is related to that in the link but it doesn't offer any solution that I can try.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT This is not resolved. I'm still looking for help.

Comment: Hey @aBadAssCowboy . making calls using Graph API is protected and it seems to be like, we need to request permission from Microsoft. Check : https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR1ax4zKyZjVBmutzKVo1pVtUQ1VJMlNTNUdJV1FKTzVZSVU4MlMwTTdOTSQlQCN0PWcu 
for requesting. 
Check the URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis   to know about the protected API's in Microsoft Teams.

Comment: @SairamTadepalli-MT Which API call from my question is a protected APIs according to you? I don't see any API calls we make in the protected apis list. Also, we don't have any issues with API calls. They are all working fine. We have issues with receiving Botframework events.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/5713 this link which I shared in my previous comments also states that, microsoft is working hard to get accurate solution for the same problem. Ticket was raised and you can find Microsoft person is also working parallelly to find the solution. Kindly follow this github chain, this may help you if there is any update from Microsoft on this specific issue.